# The sign of a signed permutation

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, coxeter-groups

There are two notions of 'sign' for signed permutations:

1. the parity of the length (that is, the minimal length of a reduced word)
2. the parity of the number of signs in the one line notation.

I will be using both of them.  Is there any standard notation I could rely on?  I am thinking of 'sign' and 'parity', but I would be very grateful for suggestions.

Comment: The set of homomorphisms of $F_2\wr_n\mathfrak{S}_n$ to $F_2=\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$ has dimension 2 over $F_2$ (for all $n\ge 2$) so there are 3 nonzero homomorphisms. I'm not sure what are the conventions. Certainly for an odd permutation of $I_n=\{-n,\dots,-1,1,\dots,n\}$, you have two naturally defined signatures: its signature as permutation of $I_n$ and the signature of the induced permutation of $\{1,\dots,n\}$. These do not coincide (for all $n\ge 1$), and are both nontrivial (for all $n\ge 2$). It's an exercise to evaluate them on Coxeter generators.

Comment: @YCor:indeed, if I understand correctly, the third is the determinant, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoctahedral_group#Subgroups

Comment: Yes, determinant of the corresponding $\{-1,1\}$-valued monomial $n\times n$-matrix.

Comment: Actually, I made a mistake: the determinant is the parity of the length. So, maybe 1. is the sign or determinant, 2. is the parity and 3. is the induced sign.

Comment: When you say length you implicitly mean "length with respect to Coxeter generators". Actually in the Coxeter generators you have two types: the special one (linked to a single other generator with a 4-labeled edge) and the other "ordinary" ones. In any word with respect to generators, you can count only the parity of the number of occurrences of the special generator, or of ordinary ones, or all. In the first case you get signature of the induced permutation of $\{1,\dots,n\}$; in the second case you get signature of the permutation of $I_n$, and in the third case you get the determinant.

Answer (score 2):

**notion 1:** Definition 2.21 of [Statistics on Signed Permutations Groups](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a83e/6c9c4303727b3b1f66302871335a514de498.pdf) defines $\text{sign}\,\sigma:=(-1)^{\ell(\sigma)}$ of the signed permutation $\sigma$ as the parity of its length $\ell(\sigma)$.

I have not found notion 2 in the literature, but if the word "sign" is taken by notion 1, that would leave the word "parity" for notion 2.